# Flink KeyBy multiple operators with or function

Tags: stream, apache-flink, processing, partitioning, flink-streaming

im trying to create a keyed stream in flink which will key by 3 fields.
I will have scenarios where I will have data in all 3 fields and scenarios where I have data in only 1 of the 3.
I need to be able to create a key selector which will be able to group together on at least once basis(like an “OR” operator).

`myStream.keyBy(key1 || key2 || key3)`

I know flink uses hash code to key streamed data and I don’t see a way to overcome this use case via hash code.

Is this not possible?

Comment: By at least once, do You mean that records as: `A(1,2,3), B(_,2,_), C(_,_,3), D(5,4,3)`
Will all end up in the same operator? `_` means that the thata is missing for this field BTW.

Comment: @DominikWosiński thanks for the response! I would like A,B,C to end up in the same operator for sure. D should not be in the same operator, i want it to be like a contains function when i finish it but i’m trying to solve the at least once use case first.

Comment: Can you provide more insight as to why you need this? There might be another solution, e.g., a custom partitioner.

Comment: @DavidAnderson right now the job works with only one key(key1 from the question) I'm keying the stream and then using a custom tumbling window with a custom trigger, every event missing this key is filtered before the keyBy. I would like to use these events and not filter them. but I wouldn't like to have two windows with the same key1. the best solution I can think of is if I could keyBy a boolean statement but that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: I would like to filter all empties and then use a boolean like: `(Objects.equals(entity1.key1, entity2.key1) || Objects.isNull(entity1.key1) || Objects.isNull(entity2.key1)) && (Objects.equals(entity1.key2, entity2.key2) || Objects.isNull(entity1.key2) || Objects.isNull(entity2.key2)) && (Objects.equals(entity1.key3, entity2.key3) || Objects.isNull(entity1.key3) || Objects.isNull(entity2.key3))`